# Why is NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML ignored when creating an NSXMLDocument with less than 12 characters?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxmldocument

I'm using `NSXMLDocument` with the `NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML` option to parse potentially "untidy" HTML. It has worked well in every scenario that I've tested, unless the string I've passed into `NSXMLDocument`'s `-initWithXMLString:options:error:` is less than 12 characters.

To demonstrate the problem, consider a trivial example in the following two lines of code:

```
NSXMLDocument *document = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<p>Hello</p>" options:NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@", [document XMLStringWithOptions:NSXMLNodePrettyPrint]);
```

This prints the following to the console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The entire string passed in was 12 characters (`<p>Hello</p>`), and though this is just a demonstration, the output is as I expect: an html document with an empty title and the paragraph tag inside of a body.

However, remove one character from this string (`<p>Helo</p>`, for example) and the output drastically changes, as though `NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML` was not specified as an option:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<p>Helo</p>
```

I've tested this with many more strings of varying length and varying tags as well (`<tr>123</tr>` vs. `<tr>12</tr>`, for example) and experience the same problem. Does anyone have any suggestions on why this would be failing to produce the HTML I would expect when providing a string that is less than 12 characters?

Comment: As an aside, padding the string with whitespace to reach 12 characters gets rid of the issue, but I'm more interested in why this behavior is as such.

Comment: A wild guess, since I've been reading a bit about Unicode recently... perhaps NSXMLDocument is examining the input to make a guess about the character encoding, looking for a Byte Order Mark etc, and this fails and produces this bug when the input is less than 12 characters?